# Getting "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" when submitting to localhost Express server

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I am building a small authentication App in Express.  When I press the login button the app hangs and then I get the error above.  Below is the code for the login pug file.

```
extends layout

block content
.main.container
.row
  .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
    h1.display-4.m-b-2 Log In
    form(method='POST' action='/login')
      div.form-group
        label(for='email') Email
        input.form-control(type='text' id='email' placeholder='email'     name='email')
      div.form-group
        label(for='password') Password
        input.form-control(type='password' id='password' placeholder='password' name='password')
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Log in
```

Any help would be appreciated. I can only conclude that, for someone reason, it is not forwarding on to the profile page.  Below is the POST route code in my index file.

```
// POST /login
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
        User.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password, function(error, user) {
            if (error || !user) {
                var err = new Error('Wrong email or password.');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            } else {
                req.session.userId = user._id;
                return res.redirect('/profile');
            }
        });
    } else {
        var err = new Error('Email and password are required.');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
    }
});
```

Below is the code to get the profile.  Not sure if it is a typo on the route.  My pug file is profile.pug

```
 // GET /profile
 router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
 if (!req.session.userId) {
 var err = new Error('You are not authorized to view this page.');
 err.status = 403;
  return next(err);
 }
 User.findById(req.session.userId).exec(function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
  return next(error);
   } else {
  return res.render('profile', {
    title: 'Profile',
    name: user.name,
    favorite: user.favoriteBook
   });
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: What does the `/profile` route on your server look like?  You can look at the network tab in the Chrome debugger to see exactly what the browser sees happening around that form post.  You can see what the server sends back and can then tell if the issue is with your `/login` route or with the `/profile` route.

Comment: forgive me for this silly question where would I find the ```/profile```route on the server?  When I Post I see bootstrap.min.js:7 error.

Comment: If it's a custom route, it would be something like `router.get('/profile', ...)`.  It could also be a static route served automatically with `express.static()`.  When you redirect to `/profile` what are you expecting your server to do and where is the code responsible for that action?

Comment: Here is the code for the profile ```router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.userId) {
    var err = new Error('You are not authorized to view this page.');
    err.status = 403;
    return next(err);
  }
  User.findById(req.session.userId).exec(function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      return res.render('profile', {
        title: 'Profile',
        name: user.name,
        favorite: user.favoriteBook
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Is that the right one?

Comment: If it's a top level route, it's the right one.  Please add the code to your question and format it appropriately.  Multi-line code is not readable in comments.  I think we're going to need to client-side debugger info from the network tab to know which exact route is giving you an empty response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167484/discussion-between-altbrian-and-jfriend00).